# Border-radius is not converting image into circle image

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When i use border-radius 50% on the image then the image is not converting into a circle image but it looks like an ellipse. Where is the problem?

I'm using bootstrap in my code.

HTML code.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="row" id="about">
                <div id="image" class="col-sm">
                        <img src="https://www.wallpaperflare.com/static/1010/124/855/alan-walker-4k-man-wearing-wallpaper.jpg" alt="Hoddie Man">
                </div>
          </div>
   </div>
```

CSS code.

```
#about{
    margin-top:3%;
}

#about img{
    width:40%;
    border-radius:50%;
}
```

Comment: Just add height same as width, it should solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Well,  `border-radius: 50%` draws an elliptical border around the box - that's exactly what  it should do.

If your box (or your image) is quadratic, the ellipse becomes a circle.

So, if the intrinsic width and height of your image is equal, your code should work, doesn't it?

Another solution may be something like:

`img { width:40vw; height:40vw; border-radius:50% }`

or
`img { width:40vmin; height:40vmin; border-radius:50% }` (may give better results on landscape oriented viewport)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add fixed width and height with pixels

```css
#about {
  margin-top: 3%;
}

#about img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row" id="about">
    <div id="image" class="col-sm">
      <img src="https://www.wallpaperflare.com/static/1010/124/855/alan-walker-4k-man-wearing-wallpaper.jpg" alt="Hoddie Man">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer worked but it does not make an image responsive.